# Windows Phone 8.1 RT - Saving and loading hub, pivot, listview position when user navigate between pages

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking way to save position of hub, pivot and listview when I'n navigate to another page, and loading it when I'm navigate back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this seems to set the NavigationCacheMode property of the page to required -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode

If you want to achieve this manually you need to find the ScrollViewer of your controls with the FindVisualChild method you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

If you got the ScrollViewer you can save the scrollposition in overridden OnNavigatingFrom method and restore it in overridden OnNavigatedTo method.

Comment: When I going back to the page I want to load position of hub/pivot/listview, but when I'm navigating to this page I expect that hub/pivot/listview reset their positions. Unfortunately NavigationCacheMode save and load position in both ways. Unless you know how to handle it to work how I want to.

Comment: If you are using DataBinding you can check the NavigationMode in OnNavigatedTo. If it is backward you do nothing, if it is forward you can set a new DataContext. When binding of Hub/Pivot/ListView changes it normally scrolls back to start.

Comment: if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
                return; else DataContext = Data;